# How to check if all documents are loaded with Firebase.util pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-util

How can I check if I have to stop calling the `loadMore()` function, because all the documents have already been loaded from the database?

In the example below I'm using Ionic, but it's the same also with ng-infinite-scroll in AngularJS apps.

This is my actual code:

**HTML:**

```
  ...

  <ion-infinite-scroll
    ng-if="!noMoreItemsToLoad"
    on-infinite="loadMore()"
    distance="5%">
  </ion-infinite-scroll>

</ion-content>
```

**JS Controller:**

```
$scope.loadMore = function(){

  console.log('Loading more docs...');

  Items.loadMore();  // calling the .next() method inside the Items service

  if( !Items.hasNext()) { $scope.noMoreItemsToLoad = true; }

  $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');

}
```

**JS Items Factory:**

```
.factory('Items', function (FIREBASE_URL, $firebaseArray,  $firebaseObject) {

  var itemsRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'items/');
  var scrollRef = new Firebase.util.Scroll(itemsRef, 'name');

  var self = {
     getAllItems : function(){ ... },

     loadMore: function(){
       scrollRef.scroll.next(4);
     },

     hasNext: function(){
       if(scrollRef.scroll.hasNext()) { return true; }
       else { return false; }
     }
  }

  return self;

}
```

Comment: See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-util/tree/master/src/Paginate#refscrollhasnext

Comment: Already tried using the`ref.scroll.hasNext()` method. The problem is it always return false so I don't know what kind of property should I use.

Comment: You should be using `hasNext()` and the snippet you posted does not. If `hasNext()` always returns false, either there's a bug, or you're using it wrong.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry, now I'm editing my original post to include it.

Answer (score 1):

Do the `scroll.next` in timeout, for example:

```
 loadMore: function(){
   $timeout(function() {
     scrollRef.scroll.next(4);
   });
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I think the solution is to modify the hasNext() function on firebase.util.js:

```
Cache.prototype.hasNext = function() {
  return this.count === -1 || this.endCount >= this.start + this.count;
};
```

I put a missing equal sign (=) before *this.start*

I hope it works for you.